# How to view the content of a C++ macro?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a macro that is dynamically generated before compilation (it's supposed to contain the build number). However I think there's some error with the way it's generated so I would like to check the content of this macro. How can I do that?

I'm using the MSVC2008 compiler.

Comment: It's in Qt Creator. I'm following the instructions there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417061/automatic-increment-of-build-number-in-qt-creator

Comment: gcc has the nice `-E` parameter that's perfect for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/p` option and **[write preprocessor output to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx)**. Or
You can use `/E` option and **[write preprocessor output to stdout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "Preprocess to a file" option on the project or file's properties to *true*. That will let you see exactly what the preprocessor emits.

(It's under Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Preprocessor.)